# Token count comparison grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

```
grammar neq;

WS
    :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
    ;


root: aGTb | bGTa | eq;


aGTb: 'a'
        |  eq  aGTb
        |  aGTb  eq
        |  aGTb  aGTb
;

bGTa: 'b'
        |  eq  bGTa
        |  bGTa  eq
        |  bGTa  bGTa
;
        
eq: 'a'  'b'
  |  'b'  'a'
  |  'a'  eq  'b'
  |  'b'  eq  'a'
  |  eq  eq
;
```

This version is too slow, however, tests:

- Random strings length 20 literals: Avg time =14 ms, Min time =0, Max time =78
- Length 40: Avg time =32, Min time =0, Max time =231
- Length 60: Avg time =83, Min time =16, Max time =416
- Length 80: Avg time =365, Min time =37, Max time =11935
- Length 100: Avg time =1442, Min time =67, Max time =25317
- Length 120: Avg time =21861, Min time =135, Max time =924769

The input for the above 924 sec parse time:

```
a b b a a a b b a a b a b a a a a b a a a a b b b a a a a b a a b 
a a a b b b a a a b b a b b b a a b b a b a b a b a b a a a a b b 
b a a b b b b a a b a b a b a a a b a b b b b b a a a b a a a b b 
a b a b a a b b b a a b b a b a a a a a a
```

Can the grammar be rewritten to faster version? (Be careful, changing say `eq` into

```
eq: 'a'  'b'
  |  'b'  'a'
  |  eq  'a'  'b'
  |  eq  'b'  'a'
  |  'a'  eq  'b'
  |  'b'  eq  'a'
  |  'a'  'b'  eq
  |  'b'  'a'  eq
;
```

is not equivalent rule rewriting, as it will not recognize `a a b b b b a a`).

Comment: What target language are you using?

Comment: `root : ('a' | 'b')+;`.

Comment: @kaby76   Remove the eq alternative from the root, to make the language to recognize non equal letter counts only.

Comment: @BartKiers It would hang in any target, wouldn't it? Java

Comment: No, for example, the Python 2 and 3 targets/runtimes are a magnitude slower than faster ones (I've seen differences as large as 20 times as slow!). But Java is a fast runtime.

Comment: It won't matter what target you choose: all targets run very slowly due to backtracking. LL(k) is O(n^(k+1)), which means a very slow parse for k> "a few" (note, n=3 here, k = 1000). AdaptivePredict() memoization will add nothing here. Even the fastest target, Cpp Release, it does not terminate after many minutes for the "1000a+b's" example. You can rewrite the rules using predicates and kleene-ops for an efficient grammar, e.g., `eq: ('a'|'b')+ { /* validate # of children % 2 == 0, # of children > 1, equal # of 'a's and 'b's */ }?;`. Is this a CS class question?

Comment: I have reduced the test case to mere 120 symbols long. I'd also suspect this grammar would be a no go for GLR parser as well.